# TypeScript: Same as Pick<...>, but with multiple fields

Tags: typescript

I use [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), but how could I write a generic PickMulti which can pick multiple fields?

```js
interface MyInterface {
  a: number,
  b: number,
  c: number
}

// this works, but I would like a generic one in number of fields
type AB = Pick<Pick<MyInterface, 'a'>, 'b'>;

// Something like this:
type PickMulti = /* how to write this?*/;
type AB = PickMulti<MyInterface, ['a', 'b']>
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`Pick` already works with multiple fields you just need to provide them as a union, not a tuple/array type:

```
interface MyInterface {
  a: number,
  b: number,
  c: number
}

type AB = Pick<MyInterface, 'a' | 'b'>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=47&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgbwChlk4AuZEAVwFsAjaAGhOXspoedYQ7sahEAvkSJh0ABxQBBAELIAvMgAKwBAGsAPBmyRYiCE2QByOMeQAfE-WMA+ANxA)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to work with arrays as in your example:

```
type PickMulti = /* how to write this?*/;
type AB = PickMulti<MyInterface, ['a', 'b']>
```

So if you have array:

```
const fields = Object.keys(object).filter(...)
// or
const fields = ['a', 'b']
```

It may be solved like this:

```
const pickArray = [...fields] as const;
type pickUnion = typeof pickArray[number];
type PickAB = Pick<MyInterface, pickUnion & keyof MyInterface>;
```